# Using .NET Core new solution has errors in the references folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created a new solution using .NET Core although the solution has errors in the references folder, I've included screen shots below.

Does anyone know why this happens?  This is straight out of the box, a new virtual machine as well.  Any help much appreciated.
Thanks,

[image: Selecting .NET Core solution]

[image: Selecting Web Api]

[image: Solution with reference errors]

[image]

If I try to run dotnet build I get the following error

PM> dotnet build
dotnet.exe : Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directoryAt line:1 char:1

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone's guidance the root of the problem was because the windows machine was a VM so the paths for the solution were networked due how to the Mac Parallel's software works.  Having created a new path at the root of the C drive the references are now loaded.  The only problem now is that when browsing http://localhost:50438/api/values/5 I get the site cannot be reached.

Comment: Does your VM have an internet connection and is able to access nuget packages site? What error do you get if you manually try to `dotnet restore`?

Comment: I've updated my question with another screen shot to show the log when attempting dotnet restore.  And yes the VM has access to the internet

Comment: And if you run `dotnet build` command?

Comment: i've updated my question but I get this error "Couldn't find 'project.json' in current directoryAt line:1 char:1"

Comment: I have a feeling there is an issue with folder paths... 
Do you run both restore and build commands in the same working folder "\\psf\Home\Desktop\CoreTest\Services"? Is it a network share?

Comment: ah you might be onto something there.  It's because it's a mac machine and the Windows VM (using Parallels) makes that path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124982/discussion-between-ignas-and-jamie).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Nuget packages are not restored. Check if you have proper nuget sources defined. 
Try using those:

```
<add key="dotnet.cli" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-cli/api/v3/index.json" />
<add key="dotnet.core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
```